# Azure - Can we use `PersistedFaceId` instead of `FaceId` for Find Similiar first query param

Tags: azure, face-api

API `Face - Face Similar` requires a `FaceId`, `FaceListId` and some optional parameters. I was wondering would a `PersistedFaceId` work instead of the returned `FaceId` from API `Face - Face Detect`?

Answer (score 0):

`Face - Face Similar` can accept either of:

1) An array of faceIds  - this is an ad-hoc array of faceIds returned by the `Detect` API that your app can aggragte

2) A faceListId - this is an ID for a `FaceList` ([see here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524b)) which is a pre-built list of persisted faceIds.

When you add a face to the Face List it will persist that face and return a persistedFaceID.

Please note the `FaceList` persistedFaceIds are different than the `PersonGroup/Person` persistedFacesIds. I don't think you can use the latter in the `Similar` API